# Android kitkat 4.4.2 - Not able to access the DB from javascript?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, sqliteopenhelper, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating and android hybrid application. In that I am downloading the xyz.db file directly from the server and placing it in  /data/data/"/app_webview/databases/file__0/ path.

I am trying to fetch the data from the xyz.db file from the javascript file which is loaded in the webview, but I am not getting the values. Is that path which I have mentioned above is correct. I am facing this issue only in ANDROID KITKAT 4.4.2. What is the solution for this?

Comment: You should place it on assets folder

Comment: @subspider then what will be the PATH

Comment: Can you show your javascript code that opens the DB?

Comment: @subspider var dbConn = openDatabase('xyzDB', '1.0', 'xyz Database', 15 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: so as far as I know opens or creates a db for you. The first parameter should be the path can you show-me how are you saving the db  in assets ? and what is your asset structure directory ?